# Light intensity set to 0 at runtime but shadows still visible

Tags: javascript, three.js

I can't find how to remove the shadows...

At runtime I do : light.intensity = 0.0;
The scene is darker (ok) but the shadows generated by the light are still visible.
I tested with a directional and a spot. I tried things (probably stupid) that do not work...

If you know how to do...
Thanks

Comment: Do you want to be able to turn on and off shadows or do you want shadows off all the time?

Comment: Oups... Sorry Gaitat : I did not see your answer... I am new here. My question was not clear : when I turn the spot on I want to see the light and the shadows generated by the spot. It works. But when I turn the spot off I no more see the light of the spot but I still see the shadows generated from the spot (which is off...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to also do `light.castShadow = false;`

Comment: I did that too but it is not working for me. Does it work for you ? EDIT : I tested again and it works now... !!